Data feed for Solana Indexer
I am thinking of building a custom transaction indexer to extract out some information from transaction on chain. Which are best source to feed data to indexer. Any good source which provides historical + current blocks of data. Its okay if lastest block comes with some delay.

You might want to check out Old faithful from Triton one where they have historical data for Solana
report: https://docs.triton.one/project-yellowstone/old-faithful-historical-archive/old-faithful-public-report
website: https://old-faithful.net/

To provide some more context to Jimii's answer, your main sources of data from a Solana validator are:

Running a validator. You'll have immediate access to anything -- this is expensive, but doable
RPC. You can fetch information from an RPC node that stores blocks. Note that if you want old blocks, they are likely stored in Google Bigtable, and not directly by the node.
Geyser. You'll need a direct connection to a validator that's providing this data. Old Faithful is a service built on top of Geyser

